# How to run a JavaScript file in Linux using SH file

Tags: javascript, linux, shell

Need to know how to run js file in linux using SH file. Currently we are running in Windows using Bat file. So i need run in Linux using sh file.
This is not a Node Js. Normal JS

Code

### ProcessColsData.js

```
db.getCollection(CollectionName).find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.release = doc.release.toString();
    doc.pid = doc.pid.toString();
    doc.DetailedRelease = doc.DetailedRelease.toString();   
    doc.appName = doc.appAcronym;
    doc.docType =  "MDEEFFORTS";    
    db.getCollection(CollectionName).save(doc);
    
    if(doc.source =='Alert') {
        _year = doc.release.substr(0, 2);
        _month = doc.release.substr(2, 2);
    } else {
        _year = doc.release.substr(0, 2);
        _month = doc.release.substr(3, 2);
    }

    _release = "20"+ _year+"."+_month;
    doc.release = _release.toString();
    db.getCollection(CollectionName).save(doc);
});
```

### Current Windows bat File

```
mongo %ipaddress%:%port%/%db% ProcessColsData.js --eval "var CollectionName='%mdeTempCollection%',releaseList=%ddreleaseList%,vendorMdeRelList=%vendorMdeRelList%,motsCollection='%motsCollection2019%'" >> ../log/ProcessColsData.log
```

**Output** will be Mongo Collection will Updated as per ProcessColsData

We will Run the Bat file which will invoke JS.
Same way i neeed to do in Linux

Comment: What is the difference between normal JS files and Node.JS files ?

Comment: Node is just a JS runtime. Among other things it provides the ability to execute JS outside of the browser. I believe you'll want to use it here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show a snippet of the file you want to run and provide a bit more context. What output do you want from it back in the shell script? What result are you hoping to achieve and why isn't NodeJS suitable here? You can only run normal JS with a browser--which browser do you wish to use? Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more info to understand what you want. Your question is extremely vague.

Comment: Presumably what you're doing here is using the mongo shell to run your JavaScript code. A Linux shell script to do the same thing as your Windows bat script is probably identical or very close to it (maybe with the addition of `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: Code and Details Added